# Why is the ICMP ECHO data length compared to the size of timeval in the original ping source code?

Tags: c, unix, ping

I've been reading through the original ping program code  (http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage/ping.text) out of interest, just to see how it was done.

I get most of it, but there is one conditional that I don't understand:

```
if (datalen >= sizeof(struct timeval)) /* can we time 'em? */
    timing = 1;
```

Where `datalen` is the length of the echo payload.

I've seen similar predicates in other C ping implementations. Why is it that a data length smaller than the size of a timeval struct prohibits timing?

**EDIT:** Inevitable late-night derp moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you need to ensure the packets are big enough to store timing data if you want to actually store timing data in them. In other words, timing works by placing a `timeval` structure *into* the payload area.

If, for example, you specified a length of 3 for the ICMP payload area when the size of the `timeval` structure was 20, it wouldn't be a good idea trying to insert it :-)

Comment: I see, I must have missed that, thanks a lot. I have trouble sometimes keeping the format of datagrams in my head, for some reason I was thinking that the timing part was part of ICMP -- but then, if it had that already, the ping program itself would be redundant :)